# Convert gridview cell contents into string array in .net

Tags: asp.net, arrays, gridview

I have a `.net` and `c#` `gridview` called gvSelected. I want to take the contents of the first column for each of the rows and put it into a string `array`.

```
string[] mytitles = new string[] { };

for (int i = 0; i < gvSelected.Rows.Count; i++)
{
mytitles[i] = gvSelected.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in
WebApplication1.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

The number of rows in `gvSelected` varies.

Comment: At which point of page life cycle are you doing this?

Comment: I'm doing this upon a button click - inside:  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { HERE }

Comment: And did you do basic debug? What is going out of bounds? What is the value of i when this happens? How many rows do you have at that moment?

Comment: Yes, I kept coming up as 0 and my array 0 but I did have 2-3 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have worked better:

```
string[] mytitles = new string[gvSelected.Rows.Count];
for (int c = 0; c < gvSelected.Rows.Count; c++)
{
   mytitles[c] = Convert.ToString(gvSelected.Rows[c].Cells[0].Text);
}
```